# Single svg file

Tags: html, svg, web

I have several .svg files in my web project. 
I add most of them to the html page using the "embed" tag, like this:

```
<embed src="css/svg/multi.svg" type="image/svg+xml"/>
```

There are two problems I'm trying to solve:

1. When entering the website it downloads each .svg file separately.  I would like them all to be downloaded together (one round trip).
2. Some of the svgs are being reused so the same svg is downloaded several times.

What I thought of doing is putting all svgs in one file and referencing them with an id or something like that. Something like "defs" and "use" but it works only in firefox so i need some other solution.

Any other solution which solves those problems is good as well (it doesn't have to be in one file)...

Thanks.

Comment: Can you show your "only works in firefox" code (both SVG and HTML)? This seems like the kind of thing that should work perfectly in **properly compliant** browsers. Have you tried having one giant SVG, and elements *not* in a defs block, and referring to those by id?

Comment: If the files are being downloaded multiple times it's probably an issue with your expiry headers rather than the SVG.

Answer (score 2):

If more browsers supported the [#svgView url syntax](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/linking.html#SVGFragmentIdentifiers) (part of SVG 1.1) you could have used that perhaps, see this [example](http://xn--dahlstrm-t4a.net/svg/html/reference-embed-multi-view.html) (works in Opera, Chrome, Safari, IE9).